# distribution of chocolate problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have 6 packet where , 10 20 30 35 50 60 are chocolate in that 6 packet.I have to distribute one packet to k children. where k=3 .Then unfair is calculated by

find=min(|sum(Xi-Xj)|) where Xi and Xj are set of number chocolate .ex:-

10 20 30 we get unfair distribution as 
|30-20|+|30-10|+|30-20|=40

10 30 35 we get unfair distribution as 
|35-30|+|35-10|+|35-30|=30
...similar for 30 35 50 as I get 40 and 35 50 60 as I get 50

So minimum of them is 30 (10 30 35)

My question is there any way to determine the minimum faster rather than performing all the calculation.

Comment: Of course if you were wore generous to these three children, you could give $60$ to the first, $50+10$ to the second and $30+35$ to the third. The infairness then would be $10$ only and you'd still have $70$ pieces of chocolate for yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For three packets, the unfairness is max minus min, times two: If $a\le b\le c$, then $$|a-b|+|a-c|+|b-c|=(b-a)+(c-a)+(c-b)=2c-2a.$$

Comment: can i apply same concept for n number of packet and k number of children.